# In TexShop, is there a way to highlight the currently editing line?

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

I was a Windows user but now becoming a Mac user.
Before, I used to use the TexMaker in Windows, and therein, the line where I am editing has a bit different color, compared to the other lines.
So, whenever I used alt+tab, I could easily recognize which point I was editing.
But in TexShop in Macbook, I need to find my editing point based only on the blinking
"I"-shape indicator.
Is there any way that makes a specific line have a different color (e.g., gray or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXShop version 4.73 now includes this feature. Update to this version, and select Changes from the Help menu. The first bullet point documented for 4.73 explains how to use this feature. I will summarize it here since there is one error in the documentation.

Assuming version 4.73, open TeXShop's Preferences. Look under the Editor tab (not the Source tab as indicated in the documentation) for a Highlight Current Line option and toggle it on. Next, look under the Themes tab in the Syntax area for a Current Line color selector. If you do not see it, quit TeXShop, delete the ~/Library/TeXShop/Themes folder (or move it to the desktop or elsewhere), and restart TeXShop. The color option should now be there and it will be red by default. Click on it to change it as desired. Save your Preferences and the feature should be working.

Comment: Thank you, after updating texshop, I could find the option.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it working for you now.